# Is there a homomorphism $f$ from $(\Bbb Z_4, +_4)$ to $(\Bbb Z, +)$, such that $f(1) =1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I think that there is no such homomorphism, at least I couldn't find it. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such homomorphism, since we have the following:

\begin{equation*}
0= f(0) = f(1 + 1 + 1 + 1) = 4f(1) \implies f(1) = 0
\end{equation*}